# passing paramters to a command from the code

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to pass some data to the to a service using a command, but I wan't to use it in code. This is what I have tried :

view.xaml.cs

```
    ViewModel.FirstVm vm1;
    public ViewPage(Models.Example example)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon(this, "logosmall.png");
        Tasks ts = new Tasks();
        var myLocation = Task.Run(() => 
        ts.GetDeviceCurrentLocation()).Result;
        var latitudeIm = myLocation.Latitude;
        var longitudeIm = myLocation.Longitude;
        vm1 = new FirstVm(latitude, longitude, latitudeIm, longitudeIm);
        routeInfo.Command = vm1.GetInfoCommand;

   }
```

view-model

```
    public FirstVm(double latitude, double longitude, double latitudeIm, double longitudeIm)
    {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitudeIm = latitudeIm;
        this.longitudeIm = longitudeIm;
    }

    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
    public double latitudeIm;
    public double longitudeIm;

    public ICommand GetInfoCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                // how to pass the parameters here
                Routes = await _ts.GetRouteInfosAsync(latitude, longitude,latitudeIm,longitudeIm);
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new View(Routes));
            });
        }
    }
```

tasks.cs

```
public async Task<List<Route>> GetRouteInfosAsync(double la, double lo, double laIm, double loIm)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=31.320475 19.824573&destination=31.33765 11.87052&key=my_keyy");
        var routes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        return routes.routes;
    }
```

Is my approach right?! Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code? If you want your code to be reviewed post it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: you can't assign 4 different values to CommandParameter.  If you need multiple values, combine them into a single object and pass that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1:

Did you set value in construct method `FirstVm()`? If so, please initialize your vm first then use it. I guess your construct should be:

```
public FirstVm(double la, double lo, double laIm, double loIm)
{
    latitude = la;
    longitude = lo;
    latitudeIm = laIm;
    longitudeIm = loIm;
}
```

In the ViewPage you should create the vm first then use it:

```
vm1 = new FirstVm(latitude, longitude, latitudeIm, longitudeIm);
routeInfo.Command = vm1.GetInfoCommand;
```

### Solution 2:

Or you can define a command with parameters like:

```
public ICommand GetInfoCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command<List<double>>(async (List<double> list) =>
        {
            Routes = await _ts.GetRouteInfosAsync(list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3]);
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new View(Routes));
        });
    }
}
//use this command in ViewPage
routeInfo.CommandParameter = new List<double> { latitude, longitude, latitudeIm, longitudeIm };
```

Please notice that we should create the instance first before using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `BindingContext = YourViewModel()` in you constructor of Page:

```
ViewModel.FirstVm vm1;
public ViewPage(Models.Example example)
{
    InitializeComponent();`
    BindingContex = new YourViewModel(parameters)
    NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon(this, "logosmall.png");
    Tasks ts = new Tasks();
    var myLocation = Task.Run(() => 
    ts.GetDeviceCurrentLocation()).Result;
    var latitudeIm = myLocation.Latitude;
    var longitudeIm = myLocation.Longitude;
    routeInfo.Command = vm1.GetInfoCommand;
    routeInfo.CommandParameter = latitudeIm;
    routeInfo.CommandParameter = longitudeIm;
    routeInfo.CommandParameter = latitude;
    routeInfo.CommandParameter = longitude;
}
```

And then in your View model you create constructor with this parameters and use it in command

Comment: I tried using what you said but the parameters in the tasks.cs are always 0. Please could you take a look at the question, for I edited it. @qubuss

Comment: OK, but you have to set binding context like I did. You have to do this in class not xaml